# terraform - remote backend. Error locking state: error acquiring the state lock: resource not found

Tags: terraform

ill start off by saying I am fairly new to using Terraform so if this is a dumb question I apologize in advanced.

So, I am getting the error listed in the title when attempting to run any "terraform plan" or "terraform apply" commands.  I am attempting to use the "remote" backend (hosted lock-site) during this exercise.  I have gotten the api key, have put the terraform{... backend remote....} into the configuration file and run terraform init.  This seems to initialize fine and I see the workspace appear under my organization.

But that is as far as it goes.  When running this configuration under the local state it provisions just fine.  When I attempt to run it under the remote state I get the above error.  Any pointers in a direction would be greatly appreciated!

Configuration File:

```
credentials "app.terraform.io" {
            token = "MyAccessToken"
}
```

provisioning configuration file:

```
terraform {
    backend "remote" {
        organization = "MyOrganization"
             workspaces {
                  name = "MyWorkSpace"
                      }
          }
```

}